# Different view route in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I can somehow change the generated and accepted routes for simple urls, in the `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

This works like a charm. However, this doesn't:

```
Router::connect('/eintrag/:id', array('controller' => 'entries', 'action' => 'view'));
Router::connect('/bearbeiten/:id', array('controller' => 'entries', 'action' => 'edit'));
```

When I try to get a route for this, via `echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'entries', 'action' => 'view', $entry['id']))`, I get `/entries/view/1`. And the url `/eintrag/1` is not accepted by the router.

How can I prettify my view and edit routes like I can do with parameterless routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a third param in your route, as you are passing it `:id` specifically.

```
// SomeController.php
public function view($id = null) {
    // some code here...
}

// routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/eintrag/:id', // e.g. /eintrag/1
    array('controller' => 'entries', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        // this will map ":id" to $id in your action
        'pass' => array('id'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

should do it.

More info @ [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

$this->Html->url() is just a Helper Function, that simply generates a URL according to paramaters passed, however when you actually open this Url then it will route request made for /eintrag/1 to /entries/view/1

Comment: Then why can it do that when I have parameterless routes?